# Trying to get a more verbose message for "Bus Error" kernel

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tshark, solid-state-drive, sigbus

I'm struggling with a python program, deployed on a Raspberry Pi, that uses tshark to monitor network traffic dumping the result on a separate file on a mounted SSD external disk.

I've tried almost every configuration possible:

- writing the output to the SD instead to the external SSD disk
- isolating the process, the method to just capture and write the file
- adding several configuration flags to set as verbose as possible

**Not tried on a separate computer as it is a remote env, and I cannot change anything else regarding HW.
**It is not clear if is HW arose (SD problem?) or SW arose https://www.wireshark.org/lists/ethereal-dev/199912/msg00027.html

Despite every test I tried, I cannot set a more verbose message apart from "Bus Error", which arises randomly after 2, 3 or 5 days of capturing without interruption.

The question is if it is possible to force the os to print more verbose messages.